# How to download ElasticSearch snapshot from repository to local machine?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, backup, elastic-stack

I'm using a small elasticsearch cluster from the elastic cloud.
I need to:

1. download one of the indices from elasticsearch to my local machine for analysis
2. set up elasticsearch node locally and restore this index into it.

In Kibana UI in section `Snapshot and Restore` I can see my snapshots and this hint:

> Use repositories to store and recover backups of your Elasticsearch
> indices and clusters.

But how do I **download the actual data from elasticsearch index to my machine** (as a bunch of jsons) and import it into elasticsearch running locally?

Comment: Hi, I don't know if that can help you. When I need do something like that I used this useful library. https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump.

Answer (score 4):

With a small cluster, and with just a few indices, I'd use the reindex api and just let your local instance index the data directly from your remote.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "https://...cloud.es.io:9243",
      "username": "user",
      "password": "pass"
    },
    "index": "source"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest"
  }
}
```

Have a look here for the official documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade-remote.html

Comment: Interesting approach, and probably preferred in most cases.
How about, if the source and destination have no connectivity, and I actually need to dump the data to file?

Comment: @Jolta I've only done this to remote storage, but the snapshot and restore api supports this. A little messier though: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html

Comment: I can't actually see how to "download" the snapshot once created like the OP wanted. Only how to create a snapshot (which I presume is stored on the disk of the ES cluster).

Comment: Creating a remote snapshot and restoring it on a local storage would mean the data is on local storage. Analyse that data is however hard. If the OP needs the data as csv for example, an external library like @Adrian mentioned in another comment would be needed.